# SQL IN BETWEEN. Comparing records and ranges (two different tables)

Tags: sql, relational-database, between, inet

I want records from `ip` which are not in a DHCP range. The `ip` table has over ten thousand records, the ranges about thousand.

```
CREATE TABLE ip (ip int);
CREATE TABLE dhcprange (start int,end int);
INSERT INTO found_ips VALUES 
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.10')),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.11')),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.12')),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.51')),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.52')
);

INSERT INTO dhcpranges VALUES
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.50'),INET_ATON('10.0.0.60'),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.70'),INET_ATON('10.0.0.100') 
);
```

(This unfortunately does not work on sqlfiddle (inet_aton isn't supported?))

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT ip FROM ip WHERE ip NOT BETWEEN(SELECT start,end FROM dhcprange)
```

Ideas?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1047 - it appears that inet_aton is supported in sqlfiddle.  What exactly wasn't working for you? From this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton I see that INET_ATON requires use of INT UNSIGNED rather than simply INT, as you have here.  Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Odd, can't seem to recreate thie problem. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT i.ip 
FROM ip i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT NULL
   FROM dhcprange d
   WHERE i.ip BETWEEN d.start AND d.end)
```

Answer (score 2):

A few ways you could do this. The best way would be to use a `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` like so:

```
SELECT ip
FROM ip
LEFT JOIN dhcpranges ON ip BETWEEN start AND end
WHERE start IS NULL
```

You could do a non-correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ip
FROM ip
WHERE ip NOT IN (SELECT ip FROM ip INNER JOIN dhcpranges WHERE ip BETWEEN start AND end)
```

Or use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.ip
FROM ip a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dhcpranges WHERE a.ip BETWEEN start AND end)
```

Comment: I see you updated your post, thanks. This would work, too. I already accepted the other answer. Have my upvote and thanks!